# Build postgres docker container with initial schema

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I'm looking to build dockerfiles that represent company databases that already exist. Similarly, I'd like create a docker file that starts by restoring a psql dump.

I have my `psql_dump.sql` in the `.` directory.

```
FROM postgres
ADD . /init_data
run "createdb" "--template=template0" "my_database"
run  "psql" "-d" "my_database"  --command="create role my_admin superuser"
run  "psql" "my_database" "<" "init_data/psql_dump.sql"
```

I thought this would be good enough to do it. I'd like to avoid solutions that use a `.sh` script. Like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600369/starting-a-postgres-container-in-docker-and-then-loading-it-with-data).

I use template0 since the psql documentation says you need the same users created that were in the original database, and you need to create the database with template0 before you restore.

However, it gives me an error:

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
```

I'm also using docker compose for the overall application, if solving this problem in docker-compose is better, I'd be happy to use the base psql image and use docker compose to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting and populating a Postgres container in Docker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600369/starting-and-populating-a-postgres-container-in-docker)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

According to the [usage guide](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) for the official PostreSQL Docker image, all you need is:

### Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_DB my_database
COPY psql_dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

The `POSTGRES_DB` environment variable will instruct the container to create a `my_database` schema on first run.

And any `.sql` file found in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` of the container will be executed.

If you want to execute `.sh` scripts, you can also provide them in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I also wasn't realizing that I needed to enter psql with `psql --username=my_user --dbname=my_database`   
that made it work the way I expected.

Comment: The subject asks for "Build postgres docker container with initial schema". But what you suggest creates the schema on startup, rather than building a container that already has that schema. If the schema takes 5 minutes to create, that's a 5 minute penalty each time it has to create a volume, rather than having it inside the actual container.

Comment: Having your data inside the image (so you can have it at container creation) is a bad idea since the docker image union file system is slow. Your data should be on a volume, thus out of the container filesystem / image filesystem

Comment: @Thomasleveil you can do it in 3 steps: first create a container as you did, then copy its data to a local host directory, and then each time you want a fresh PostreSQL, start a PostreSQL container which it's volume is working with a copy of this local host directory.

Answer (score 9):

As said in the comments, @Thomasleveil answer is great and simple if your schema recreation is fast. 
But in my case it's slow, and I wanted to use docker volumes, so here is what I did

1. First use docker image as in @Thomasleveil answer to create a container with postgres with all the schema initialization

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres
WORKDIR /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ADD psql_dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
EXPOSE 5432
```

2. then run it and create new local dir which contains the postgres data after its populated from the “psql_dump.sql” file: `docker cp mypg:/var/lib/postgresql/data ./postgres-data`
3. Copy the data to a temp data folder, and start a new postgres docker-compose container whose volume is at the new temp data folder:

startPostgres.sh:

```
rm -r ./temp-postgres-data/data
mkdir -p ./temp-postgres-data/data
cp -r ./postgres-data/data ./temp-postgres-data/
docker-compose -p mini-postgres-project up
```

and the docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: mini-postgres
    image: postgres:9.5
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./temp-postgres-data/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Now you can run steps #1 and #2 on a new machine or if your psql_dump.sql changes. And each time you want a new clean (but already initialized) db, you can only run startPostgres.sh from step #3.
And it still uses docker volumes.

Comment: `ADD psql_dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` can be shortened to `ADD psql_dump.sql .`, since you're already in that WORKDIR

Comment: Why not just using a volume to add the sql to docker-entrypoint-initdb.d ?

Answer (score 7):

@Thomasleveil's answer will re-create the database schema at **runtime**, which is fine for most cases.

If you want to recreate the database schema at **buildtime** (i.e. if your schema initialization is really slow) you can invoke the stock `docker_entrypoint.sh` from within your Dockerfile.

However, since the `docker_entrypoint.sh` is designed to start a long-running database server, you have to add an extra script to exit the process after database initialization but before booting the long-running server.

### Dockerfile (with *build time* database initialization)

```
# STAGE 1 - Equivalent to @Thomasleveil
FROM postgres AS runtime_init
ENV POSTGRES_DB my_database
COPY 1-psql_dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

# STAGE 2 - Initialize the database during the build
FROM runtime_init AS buildtime_init_builder
RUN echo "exit 0" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/100-exit_before_boot.sh
ENV PGDATA=/pgdata
RUN docker-entrypoint.sh postgres

# STAGE 3 - Copy the initialized db to a new image to reduce size.
FROM postgres AS buildtime_init
ENV PGDATA=/pgdata
COPY --chown=postgres:postgres --from=buildtime_init_builder /pgdata /pgdata
```

##### Important Notes

- The stock postgres image will run initialization scripts [in alphabetical order](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/e8ebf74e50128123a8d0220b85e357ef2d73a7ec/12/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh#L156), so ensure that your database restoration scripts appear *earlier* than the `exit_before_boot.sh` script created in the Dockerfile.

  - This is demonstrated by the `1` and `100` prefixes shown above. Modify them to your liking.
- **Database updates to a running instance of this image will not be persisted across reboots** since the `PGDATA` path where the database files are stored no longer maps to a volume mounted from the host machine.

##### Further Reading

- Instructions from the authors of the official postgres image about [writing your own `custom_entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/pull/496). This is arguably the more "official" way to solve this problem, but I personally find my approach easier to understand and implement.
- [A demo of this concept for PostgreSQL 9](https://medium.com/fintech-studios-engineering/creating-fast-lightweight-testing-databases-in-docker-2a8164d2f519), which uses the `--help` flag to exit the `docker-entrypoint.sh` before the long-running server boots. Unfortunately, this [no longer works as of December 3, 2019](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/636#issuecomment-593355532)
- Two discussions [(1)](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/319) [(2)](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/433) of this same question from the [official docker postgres repository](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres).

Comment: This is super helpful. As a note, one pattern I use to order files like this is 001, 100, 999, etc. It protects against alphabetic sorting going awry. 100 is sorted before 2, for instance. Also, `PGDATA` was not being respected for me, so I had to use the default `/var/lib/postgresql/data/`

Comment: I would recommend using 
RUN echo "docker_temp_server_stop && exit 0" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/99_exit_before_boot.sh

instead of just exit for a graceful shutdown of postgres. If you don't on next start there will be a corruption check.