# Failed to build postgres docker container with initial schema

Tags: docker

I want to setup some initial tables in docker postgres.

I look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34753186/72437 , thought it would be straight forward.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: ./postgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

### postgres/postgres.sql

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    client_id character varying(36) NOT NULL,
    value character varying(255)
);
```

### postgres/Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:latest
ENV POSTGRES_DB my_db
ADD postgres.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Then, I execute

1. docker-compose build
2. docker-compose up

I try to exam my database by

```
docker ps
docker exec -it bb54abc9be16 bash
root@bb54abc9be16:/# psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres
psql (10.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges

-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

Seem like `my_db` DB and `my_table` table are not created.

May I know what thing I had missed out?

Comment: Can you try with postgres:10 ?

Comment: Do you mean `FROM postgres:10` ?

Comment: and `docker-compose version`?

Comment: Yes. From postgres:10

Comment: I checked this with `10`. worked fine

Comment: My docker-compose version is `docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a96`? Are you using the exact command as I do?

Comment: Using `FROM postgres:10` will still fetch 10.1 still. I don't think that related to postgres version problem

Comment: I run exact same comand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `docker-compose down` command to cleanup your existing container and volume.

I have followed your process. And it works for me.

```
$ docker-compose down
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up
```

When I use `docker-compose up` first time, It creates a container and local [volume](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/10/Dockerfile#L126) for `/var/lib/postgresql/data`.

```
docker-compose images
   Container       Repository      Tag       Image Id      Size 
----------------------------------------------------------------
test_postgres_1   test_postgres   latest   4514d60c85fb   274 MB
```

Then it starts with same container and volume with each time in your case.

So if you first use `docker-compose up` when you didn't provide init script, and then change Dockerfile to add init script. It will not work unless you delete your existing Container.

Because, in local volume [PG_VERSION](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/10/docker-entrypoint.sh#L56) file is created. And which is checked before database initialization.

Thats why

```
$ docker-compose down
```

This will clean up your existing container and local volume.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. `docker-compose down` really help.